# Privacy Challenges in Applying Fully Homomorphic Encryption to Find Closest Shops Based on Zipcodes

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, differential-privacy

### Context

To learn about fully homomorphic encryption (FHE) and a new language I implemented the [Paillier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) [cryptosystem](https://blog.openmined.org/the-paillier-cryptosystem/) in Go, and I thought it would be fun to apply it to the following interaction:

> A customer wants to find the closest shop near its zipcode (2345), and submits it to a website, that computes what the closest shop is without learning the zipcode of the customer.

### Assumptions

- For simplicity, I assume that the between the customer and the shop, equals the numerical distance between the zipcode of the customer and the zipcode of the nearest shop.
- I distinguish three cases:

1. The zipcode of the customer is known to equal that of a zipcode of the stores because it is a continuous list of integer zipcodes, and every zipcode has a store.
2. The zipcode of the customer is equal to that of a store, even though the list of store zipcodes consists of non-continuous integers.
3. The zipcode of the customer does not equal that of a store, and the list of store zipcodes consists of non-continuous integers.

### Note

I am aware this is not an appropriate use-case for FHE, because the database of shop zipcodes is not private/secret, (so the store can just send the list of zipcodes to the user and let the user find the closest zipcode in its javascript browser). This is for learning purposes about the FHE applications only.

### Approach

Since the Paillier cryptosystem is only able to do addition, **OR** multiplication (and hence subtraction and division), I thought one could compute the find the closest zipcode with the following procedure:

1. The customer public (encryption) key is ( n , g )
2. The private (decryption) key is ( λ , μ )
3. Customer encrypts its zipcode using its private key, then submits those 3 values to the website.
4. The website knows which encrypted value represents which element (but not what the zipcode value is.
5. The website computes (without encryption) the largest distance possible between any zipcodes the customer may submit, and the actual shop zipcodes. Then it adds +1 to this value and encrypts this distance with the customer public key.
6. The website encrypts the shop zipcodes, and a 0 and a 1 with the public key of the customer.
7. The website adds the maximum distance to each encrypted zipcode, and then subtracts the encrypted customer zipcode from the list of encrypted zipcodes, yielding the positive, encrypted distance (proxy) between the customer and the shops.
8. The website starts subtracting the encrypted 1 from the encrypted positive differences, until one of them equal the encrypted 0 value. Then it returns the zipcode belonging to the distance that reached 0 first.

### Issue

However, if the zipcode list is continuous and complete, the website knows what the zipcode of the customer was after all, by determining which zipcode they returned.

### Question

(How) is it possible to use FHE and prevent the website from finding out what the zipcode of the customer was after all? (For example by applying some mixing/randomization in the list, or by using a different procedure to determine the closest shop)

Comment: It is possible to do with FHE, however, the calculation time is the problem. You can encrypt the zipcodes and start from there, however, this is a nearly impossible task to achieve since the evaluator need to calculate everything under encryption.. 6th is flawed, be carefull

Comment: The Paillier cryptosystem is multiplicatively homomorphic, OR (with some limitations) additively homomorphic, but AFAIK not both.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you for your sharp observation, I was not aware one had to choose between addition and multiplication in Paillier's cryptosystem. I took the liberty to remove the multiplication in the approach by adding a max possible distance that is computed non-encrypted, on the website side. This implies the approach now only contains addition. I appreciate your suggestion, and to prevent spiraling off into the example approach, would like to emphasize that the question is about how one could prevent de-anonymisation in the given context, even if that is with a completely different approach.

Comment: Rather than jumping to homomorhic encryption, we should define what's wrong with the simple alternative: server precomputes zipcodes closest to each zipcode with a shop, sends the whole list of <shop zipcode, closest zipcodes> to customer. Customer, knowing their zipcode, picks the right entry. Anonymity is perfect. One problem is communication size, which even with compression can be an issue. But there are practical solutions, like the customer sends their zipcode modulo 7, which is not much scary an anonymity leak, and allows to trim the list by about that factor.

Comment: At least with additively homomorphic Paillier encryption, the approach in the question (trying to compute the closest-shop's zipcode server-side and sending it encrypted to the client) is bound to failure. Basic problem is that the search in step 8 just can't work, for the server can't test for equality. Any selection has to be done client-side. And then using Paillier encryption becomes useless, plus it has large ciphertext size (a cryptogram is at least a wide as $n^2$ or twice the plaintext, whichever is larger).